# Screen recording with gst-launch-0.10 on CentOS 6.7 + Gnome 2.28

Tags: centos, video, video-streaming, gnome

I need to make short videos (1-2 minutes long) capturing the screen. Unfortunately I cannot install new software on this machine, so all I have is gst-launch and gst-launch-0.10 (of course, together with gst-inspect, gst-typefind, gst-xmlinspect, gst-xmllaunch)

Searching on the internet I built this command but all it records is some sounds with no videos, and it is over 24h long.

```
gst-launch -v ximagesrc startx=0 starty=0 endx=800 endy=600 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1" ! filesink location=output.avi
```

How can I fix the command in order to be able to record the screen?